# How to make IntelliJ IDEA use javac for Java and scalac for Scala?

Tags: java, scala, compiler-construction, compilation, intellij-idea

In my IDEA project a Scala module depends on a Java module. When I try to compile the Scala module, only scalac is triggered. It compiles both Java and Scala sources.

I'd like scalac to compile only the Scala module, because javac is much faster for Java sources (and my Java project is a big one).
**How to make IDEA use different compiler for different modules?**

---

**My workaround** is to (for each dependency to Java module):

1. Delete module dependency in project configuration
2. Add dependency to appropriate compile output directory "MyJavaModule/target/classes"

Obviously I'm not happy with that, because every time I reimport Maven project I need to repeat all of this to have fast compilation. I hope somebody knows a better way.

---

**Clarification:** I'd like to stress, that tools like SBT or Maven don't solve my problem. It is not about compilation alone. It's about compilation in IDEA, required for things like Scala Worksheet or running unit tests from IDEA. My goal is to have full range of IDEA niceties (syntax highlighting, intelligent auto-completion, auto-imports, etc) with compilation speed of SBT. Now I have to either tolerate long compilation times (due to dependencies to my Java module) or to use bare-bones REPL and testing in SBT.

Comment: Why does it matter which tool does the compilation?

Comment: Because IDEA needs to do the compilation itself if I want to run tests or Scala Worksheet from within it. And I want it, because it works better than from SBT console. Also, the tool matters because speed of compilation depends on it.

Comment: Syntax highlighting, auto-completion, auto-importing do not depend on IDEA doing the compilation. Those things are driven off its internally derived indexes of the source code. Apart from the Worksheet functionality, you'll be much further ahead to use SBT to define your project and the sbt-idea plug-in to generate the IDEA project definitions files. Unit testing is just as fast (probably faster) in SBT and can be made completely automatic (triggered by the Save command in IDEA) by simply executing `~test`.

Comment: I agree, SBT is great for unit testing if one doesn't mind switching between windows (don't you also have to have the whole testsuite run each time?). Though SBT REPL is clearly worse than IDEA Scala Console. Compilation by IDEA is still needed if I want to use IDEA Scala Console unless one can switch it off somehow. I haven't found such option yet... ...oh, wait... ...I've just found it.... WOW! One just needs to remove "make" step in run configuration. Of course now that means that I need to switch to SBT completely from Maven :) But I think that I'll go that way :)

Comment: You can use the `test-only` task (command) in SBT which takes a glob pattern to match against fully qualified test class names and runs only those that match the glob. The SBT "console" is the Scala REPL (plus the project's class-path) and it is arguably inferior to either Eclipese's or IDEA's Worksheets, but I personally find little I want to test or experiment with "manually" that cannot be done in the REPL.

Comment: Overflow from the previous comment: If having a separate window is somehow onerous to you, you can use the SBT plug-in for IDEA which integrates SBT's operation within an IDEA window. This has (to me) one big advantage: errors from the compiler (and tests?) are hyperlinked to the source code.

Comment: `test-only` is acceptable for me when I work TDD-style to make some test pass. Still it's inferior to just launching the test with a keyboard shortcut. Of course you still need to switch between windows unless you use the SBT plugin for IDEA (by the way that plugin appears interesting, I'll try it out).

Comment: Clearly this is a matter of opinion. I don't place a high value (at all) on so-called TDD and I have the luxury in most circumstances of having multiple monitors (one very large, one a 15" Retina display), so I can always see my source code and the SBT window by simply shifting my gaze.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randall Schulz has asked **the right question** in the comment: "**Why does it matter which tool does the compilation?**"
Up until now I believed that IDEA needs to compile all classes itself if you want to use its nice features (like IDEA's Scala Console or running tests from within it). I was wrong.

In fact, IDEA will pick up classes compiled by any other tool (like the great SBT for instance). You just need to assure that all classes are up-to-date before using any of IDEA's helpful features. The best way to do it is:

1. launch continuous incremental compilation in the background (for
   example by issuing "~ compile" in SBT)
2. remove "make" step in IDEA's
   run configurations

That's all! You can then use all cool features of IDEA (not only syntax highlighting and code completion, but all auto-imports in Scala Console, quickly running selected unit tests) without switching between different windows.
That's the workflow I missed until now! Thanks to everybody for all the comments about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a dependency management suite like Apache Ivy or Apache Maven. Then put your Java source in a separate artifact, and have your Scala project be dependent on the Java project artifact.

If you go the Maven route, there is a [Scala plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Comment: Really? That hard? It is close to be unusefull. Any simpler way?

Comment: That's not relevant. I'm using Maven already. IDEA generated its own modules from maven model. Whatever dependency management suite you choose you'll end up with the same problem. It's just because IDEA uses its own built-in module management for its own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to get compiled Scala and Java files is SBT - Simple Build Tool. Just create a project (+ add dependencies and so on) and compile it. Scala + Java compilation works out of the box. I've switched to SBT from Maven.

If you have a complex POM or if you have another reason not to migrate to SBT, you can try to configure the POM. Just adding (and possibly configuring) the Scala plugin should be enough. I hope it will not break the Java support.

Comment: My question is about compilation in IDEA - required for running unit tests and Scala Worksheet from within the IDE (where I get full auto-completion, auto-imports, syntax highlighting, etc). So while SBT is great (I use it in some other projects), I prefer to use it just for building and to use IDEA for editing and experimentation.

Comment: I use IDEA and compile SBT project outside of it. Autocompletion works well. There are two plugins for cooperation between IDEA and SBT. The first one generates a IDEA project from SBT (and it works well, although regenerating the project after adding a dependency is needed), the second one is an IDEA plugin that adds SBT support. I don't have much experience with the second one, but it might work well.

Comment: I know that setup, I've worked with it. Yet it doesn't beat the convenience of IDEA-integrated Scala Console (Ctrl+Alt+Space anybody?) and the ability to edit and quickly run unit tests from within the IDE.

Comment: Tests can be runned automaticaly by ~test command, console can be runned by console command. It would be great to do it from IDEA, but SBT is good-enough for me.